# How to change brightness using Imagick?

Tags: image, imagick, brightness

I am trying to change only the brightness of an image using imagick PHP object, I found only the modulateImage function that accepts three parameters "Brightness,Saturation and Hue" but I do not know what the relationship between them to just change brightness is. I only want to change brightness and keep the rest the same. Is it possible? How?

Comment: What happens when you set the parameters you don't want to change to `0` as per http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.modulateimage.php ?

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: as the example states here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/imagick.modulateimage.php zou should leave hue and saturation to 100 (percent) and adjust the brightness accordingly

Comment: http://www.phpimagick.com/Imagick/modulateImage

Answer (score 1):

Imagick::[modulateimage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.modulateimage.php) is the correct function to use to adjust any of the brightness, contrast or hue of an image.

There is an online example you can fiddle with on the [PHP Imagick example site](https://www.phpimagick.com/Imagick/modulateImage).